# Why does a higher weight of a child view mean less pace is taken?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have noticed when playing with weighted layouts (one widget takes 30% of screen and the other 70%) that in order to get 30% of the screen taken I need to use a weight of .7 on the widget (this case a button) and to get 70% of space taken I need to use a weight of .3 (this case a relative layout).

Can someone tell me the logic for making a larger weight take up less space.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your views width set to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` it behaves as you just mentioned in your question, which is the opposite of what one would expect. If you set the width to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` or `android:layout_height="0dp"` it will work as you intended.

Comment: You are right. I played around with those values and it does as you said thanks.

Comment: Although, it messes up when using fragments. The fragment just disapears instead of transitioning like it is supposed to (and did before). But still thanks for the info.